# How do I download a file from my Ubuntu EC2 Instance to my local windows machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu Amazon EC2 instance and I am connecting through putty. I want to download a file from that machine to my local windows machine. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [winscp](http://winscp.net/), to download via SSH.

Answer (score 1):

As Stone has suggested, you can use a Windows SCP tool to pull it from the Windows side.  Or you could share the drive from the Windows side and use smbclient on the Ubuntu box to mount the windows file system, and push it from the linux side.  Or you could use a USB stick.

**Edit** in the light of Alex's comments: he's probably right about smbclient, and the USB idea is silly (I missed the bit about the data centre).  Putty also has an SCP implementation, `pscp`, which would do a similar job to WinSCP.

Comment: The SMB side will most likely not work, however, as this Linux server is in a Data Center and his Windows machine is NATed behind a seperate router, so unless you want to port forward SMB this would be quite long winded.